# PHP Code to pull in Amazon product reviews (AWS)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, review

When I google for this subject, it looks like Amazon has been pretty protective, and only allows an ugly iFrame to show reviews on our own website.

That said, there are discussions which talk about iFrame content being pulled in through programming and displaying it on one's own: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=197867

But it's certainly not easy to find working code samples of PHP authenticating at AWS, then pulling in reviews for a specified product. Does anyone have any pointers?

Many thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like the Zend Framework thingie works anymore. Let alone the Amazon Service for customer reviews, they seem to be having problems even with basic functionality that is much more straightforward even outside Zend framework. 

Anyway, please let me know how to "accept" an answer. I only see comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can display reviews of a product reviews from amazon.com in an iframe by setting the source of iframe to "[http://www.amazon.com/product-reviews/B00891PV0G](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00891PV0G)"

replace "B00891PV0G" with your ASIN

Comment: That;s almost exactly what the question was *not*. I was wondering if there's a proper API to pull in reviews. Apparently there isn't. :)